# Nuxt.jsのESlintとPrettierについて

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, prettier, eslint

Nuxt.jsの初学者です。Nuxt.jsのプロジェクトの作成をする際にESLintの利用を選択すると.eslintrc.jsが自動的に作成されpackage.jsonにもeslintが書かれているとことだったのですが作成したプロジェクトには.eslintrc.jsがありません。

```
nuxt-test
├── README.md
├── assets/
├── components/
├── layouts/
├── middleware/
├── node_modules/
├── nuxt.config.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── pages/
├── plugins/
├── static/
└── store/
```

Choose linting toolsはESLintを選択しました。
一点気がかりなのが

https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app
https://ja.nuxtjs.org/guide/installation/

共に質問で

Check the features needed for your project

があるとのことでしたが聞かれませんでした。リポジトリのprompts.jsも
確認しましたがありませんでした。

代わりに

Choose development tools

の質問がありましたがこちら関係ありますでしょうか？

またもしよろしければESLint、Prettier周りの設定（.eslintrc.jsとVSCodeのsetting.json）はこうした方がいいよっていうのがあればご教示いただければと思います。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: こちら解決しました。Choose linting toolsの際にESLintを選んでいると思っていましたが、スペースでESLint,Prettierを選択していませんでした。

Comment: さん> もし問題が解決したのであれば、解決方法を回答として投稿した上で、質問を解決済みにしていただけませんか？

Answer (score 0):

こちら解決しました。Choose linting toolsの際にESLintを選んでいると思っていましたが、スペースでESLint,Prettierを選択していませんでした。

<sub>-- この回答は、質問者さんによる[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59510/nuxt-js%E3%81%AEeslint%E3%81%A8prettier%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6#comment64203_59510)での自己解決報告を、コミュニティ wiki 回答として再投稿したものです。</sub>